# Executions shutdown in Java makes some troubles

Tags: java

```
ExecutorService exec = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();
for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
exec.execute(new LiftOff());
}
```

And I got runtime error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.util.concurrent.RejectedExecutionException: Task producer.consumer.problem.LiftOff@4807ccf6 rejected from java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor@52e5376a[Shutting down, pool size = 1, active threads = 1, queued tasks = 0, completed tasks = 0]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$AbortPolicy.rejectedExecution(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:2048)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.reject(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:821)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.execute(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1372)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$DelegatedExecutorService.execute(Executors.java:628)
    at producer.consumer.problem.ProducerConsumerProblem.main(ProducerConsumerProblem.java:18)
Java Result: 1
```

When I comment

```
exec.shutdown();
```

I won't get any errors.
How to repair that?

Comment: When do you call shutdown()? It seems like you shut it down before executing tasks. Why do you do that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have to assume you did not just put the `shutdown` after the for loop, because that should work. You can only have this if you are calling shutdown from a different thread.

Since you only allow 1 thread, each `LiftOff` is executed in sequence. The other ones are put on a queue to be executed later. When you do a `shutdown()`, nothing can be add anymore. You need to wait until everything is added before shutting down the service to avoid the exception.

However, if you want to make sure everything you added is also executed, you need to wait. To wait, use the `submit()` method instead of `execute`. This will return a `Future` that allows you to wait by executing `get()`.

Comment: +1 you only have to wait until everything is *added* before shutting down.

Comment: You are right @PeterLawrey, I have updated my answer to make that clearer

Comment: If you want to await until the tasks are completed you can use awaitTermination() but only after you have used shutdown().